# Program that keeps track of packages with barcode

Tags: barcode

I am currently implementing a web app with the goal of keeping track of the location of all the packages in a company I am working for. Our plan is to have a barcode for each package and scan that barcode at the different sectors of the company, indicating where they are. The problem is that I have no idea where to start. I've done some research on Google but haven't found much. My main questions are:

- How do barcodes work in the first place?
- How do you program with barcodes? Is there a specific language I should use? Do I have to buy anything?
- How do you read barcodes and enter them in your program and how do you generate them in the first place?
- Any hints on how I should proceed with my implementation?

I look forward to hearing back from you as I need to implement this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but I'll do my best to answer:

> How do barcodes work in the first place?

Essentially, for this type of project, you can think of the barcodes you're going to be implementing as merely serial numbers. If you really want to know how barcodes *work*, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode) has a pretty good write up - but essentially, at this level, just think of them as a serial number, encoded in such a way that a machine can read it.

In your web app, you'd be taking a number (say, 42) that has no meaning on its own, and associating with a package and a location.

> How do you program with barcodes? Is there a specific language I should use? Do I have to buy anything?

You don't really "program" with barcodes per se... Again, it's just a machine readable implementation of some kind of information. In terms of "specific language", just build your web app as you already are, and add, say, an extra integer field. The integer doesn't mean anything on it's own - it's just going to be what's printed in the barcode. In this use case, you don't even have to have a barcode per se - you could just write it on the box! The usefulness of barcodes comes in speed and accuracy of data entry - you'd be having a computer device scan the barcode and type it in instead of a human.

> How do you read barcodes and enter them in your program and how do you generate them in the first place?

It doesn't sound like you're at the point where you're doing any kind of machine vision or anything, so the most common entry method would be to buy a basic USB barcode scanner, like a Symbol LS2208. Use the manual that comes with it (or you can download the manual) to configure it as a keyboard emulation device - that way, your user would just select a field in the web app, scan, and the scanner would type out whatever was stored in the barcode (in the example above, the number 42).

As far as generating, depending on your volume, you have lots of options. For low volumes, you can find a generator online and print them out onto Avery label-type sheets using an inkjet or laser printer. You could also find a barcode font and print right from, say, Word, onto a label sheet. For higher volumes, you could purchase specialized software and use a label printer, or you can even write this yourself. Personally, I have a Zebra LP2844 with a network interface, and I wrote some custom PHP to send commands in the printer's native language (EPL2) over a socket to print onto roll labels.

EDIT: You'd probably want to use either Code128 or Code39. These are two different "symbologies" (types of barcode) that are appropriate for what it sounds like you're doing. They're 1-dimensional (like UPC codes and not like QR codes), so a cheap reader can decode them, and they're pretty flexible and VERY common.

> Any hints on how I should proceed with my implementation?

Just think of barcodes, the way that it sounds like you want to use them, as arbitrary serial numbers that don't mean anything on their own. For example, doing this sort of box tracking in a previous warehouse environment, we printed THOUSANDS of unique serial numbered barcode labels. Those labels didn't have ANY value until they were attached to a box and a picker started to put stuff into that box. They were just numbers. Just remember to keep them unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me immensely! I'd upvote you if I could, but I am new to Stack Overflow.